# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined Google Spreadsheets API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to fetch players list from Wargaming API to Google Spreadsheet. This is the code:

```
function playersList() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    const initUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        'https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/globalmap/eventrating/?application_id=e631b3284e60a8d5b589545bbaa6b3af&front_id=thunderstorm_bg&event_id=thunderstorm&limit=100&page_no=1',
    );
    const initJson = initUrl.getContentText();
    var initData = JSON.parse(initJson);
    const numOfSites = initData['meta']['page_total'];

    const urls = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < numOfSites; i++) {
        let url = `https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/globalmap/eventrating/?application_id=e631b3284e60a8d5b589545bbaa6b3af&front_id=thunderstorm_bg&event_id=thunderstorm&limit=100&page_no=${i}`;
        urls.push(url);
    }

    var data = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < numOfSites - 1; x++) {
        var loopUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[x]);
        var loopJson = loopUrl.getContentText();
        var DATA = JSON.parse(loopJson);
        data.push(DATA);
    }

    for (var z = 0; z < numOfSites - 1; z++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < 99; y++) {
            sheet
                .getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1)
                .setValue([`data${i}`['data'][y]['rank']]);
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently an issue is `.setValue([`data${i}`['data'][y]['rank']]);`
Error returned is: **TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break your `.setValue` down:

```js
[`data${i}`['data'][y]['rank']]
// with some formatting and brackets addded:
[ (`data${i}`)['data'][y]['rank'] ]
// split in statements
const str = `data${i}`;
[ str['data'][y]['rank']
```

Your `data${i}` is a string, and strings don't have a `.data` field, thus resulting in `undefined`. Then you perform `[y]` where `y` is `0` during the first loop, and that's why you get that error.

I assume you meant to do `data[i]` instead of

```
`data${i}`
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for help. The only reason i had `data${i}` in here was because I had these objects each in different variable instead of all of them in one array. I changed it to `data[i]`, I'm getting a different error now though : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: It seems I read your code wrong and that `i` should be `z`, so `data[i]` wouldn't work (it _should_ error that `i` doesn't exist, but maybe it does in your code)_, my bad. At least now that you're properly using `obj[key]`, you can just check whether `obj` looks like what you expect and that `key` is indeed part of `obj`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code runs for 4 minutes already but i guess it's due to Wargaming API limitations. I honestly don't know why I didn't notice the `z` swapped to `i` mistake myself.